# Android RxJava Observable.interval() doesn't stop emitting items

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have a static field

```
 private static Subscription timer;
```

and two static methods:

```
public static void setTimer() {
    timer = Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.computation())
            .doOnNext(tick -> update(tick))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
}

public static void removeTimer() {
    if (timer != null && !timer.isUnsubscribed()) {
        timer.unsubscribe();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

Guessing after unsubsription Observable have to stop emitting items.
However it doesn't work. If function updatePrices is

```
private static void update(long tick) {
    Log.d(TAG, "tick");
}
```

Logs continue to be printed after calling removeTimer().

So the question is how to stop emitting items in my observable correctly?

## Solved

The issue was in double calling of setTimer().

However I still have a question. Can anybody explain why is the old copy of timer still continues to emit items after the second call of setTimer()?

Comment: I'd tried your code and I don't see any logs printed after `removeTimer` is called. Could you verify that you are not calling the `setTimer`  again from somewhere after the `removeTimer` call?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I found an issue. Actually the problem was in double calling of setTimer() before removeTimer(). However this behavior looks a bit magically for me, because I guessed that the second call of setTimer() should just replace the old observable + subscriber with the new one. Could you explain it?

Comment: Each `setTimer` call creates a new subscription(`timer`) thereby replacing the old one. When you call `removeTimer` it is applied to the last subscription, thereby leaking others. You can avoid that by checking for null before creating a new one. `if(timer == null || timer.isUnsubscribed()){ timer=...}`

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe too late, But may it help others!**

```
Observable.interval(TICK_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(v -> v * TICK_MILLIS) // use to map value to onNext func,
                .takeUntil(v -> v > MAX_TICKS) // Stop Timer here.
                .take() // You can use take to stop timer after N count
                .subscribe(this::onNext, Log::d ,this::onComplete);
```